# How to get k8s master logs on EKS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am looking for these logs:

```
/var/log/kube-apiserver.log
/var/log/kube-scheduler.log
/var/log/kube-controller-manager.log
```

In EKS user does not have access to the control plane and can't see these files directly.

I am aware of [CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/logging-using-cloudtrail.html) integration announced by AWS. But it shows events not from k8s API, but AWS EKS API like `CreateCluster` event. Also the open question how to get scheduler and controller manager logs.

There is no pods for api and controller in pods list.

```
$ kubectl get po --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                             READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   aws-node-9f4lm                   1/1       Running            0          2h
kube-system   aws-node-wj2cg                   1/1       Running            0          2h
kube-system   kube-dns-64b69465b4-4gw6n        3/3       Running            0          2h
kube-system   kube-proxy-7mt7l                 1/1       Running            0          2h
kube-system   kube-proxy-vflzv                 1/1       Running            0          2h
```

There is no master nodes in the node list

```
$ kubectl get nodes
NAME                        STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
ip-10-0-0-92.ec2.internal   Ready     <none>    9m        v1.10.3
ip-10-0-1-63.ec2.internal   Ready     <none>    9m        v1.10.3
```

Comment: Have you tried `kubectl logs` from a remote node, with valid $HOME/.kube/config? [EKS Userguide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/eks-ug.pdf)

Comment: yes, I can get the kubelet logs. But the question is about master components not worker ones

Comment: If you ask for the Nodes, do the control plane nodes show up in that list? Because if so, I would expect a DaemonSet that targets those nodes could then use a `volume: hostPath:` and egress the logs in a manner of your choosing

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel no, I see only two worker nodes when ask `kubectl get nodes`

Comment: any updates on this one?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/04/amazon-eks-now-delivers-kubernetes-control-plane-logs-to-amazon-/

Answer (score 2):

Logs can be send to [CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/pricing/) (not free of charge). The following logs can be individually selected to be send to CloudWatch:

- API server
- Audit
- Authenticator
- Controller Manager
- Scheduler

Logs can be enabled via UI or AWS CLI. See [Amazon EKS Control Plane Logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/control-plane-logs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Things like kube-api server logs, the kube-scheduler logs, the kube-controller manager logs, etc. will be available in CloudWatch logs.  While (as you have stated) EKS API calls will be logged to cloudtrail.

**I take that back, I guess AWS EKS has not gotten around to that yet.  You will need to use an EFK stack to get the logs.

Someone has already put together a quick how-to:
https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-workshop-for-kubernetes/tree/master/02-path-working-with-clusters/204-cluster-logging-with-EFK

Comment: This is about master logs & EKS. How do we access kubernetes's components logs when using AWS hosted EKS